# how to remove slashes from my json result with cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, json

I've built a REST webservice and I want to remove the slashes from my json result. I have some data stored in my DB, which one of the fields contains a websitelinks.I can access them through my normal-view which is html and through my json-view. The normal returns de links normal but the json ads slashes to it like:

```
       http:\/\/mywebsite\/company\/upload\/siteman\/thumbnails\/carr\/
```

How can i remove this? Here is my cakephp code:

```
       // De html view
       <h2>View all posts</h2>

    <table>
     <tr>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Body</th>
     </tr>

     <?php foreach($images as $image):?> 
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $image['Image']['id'];?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $image['Image']['plaatjes'];?></td>
      </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

    // The json view 
    <?php
    echo json_encode($images);
    ?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? That's perfectly fine JSON and the slashes will disappear when decoding it.

Comment: Because i need to access this json through a mobile app. So the websitelinks in the json results must be accessible directly.

Comment: Why does a mobile app make a difference? Aren't you *decoding* the JSON on the client?

Comment: because i dont want the device to use extra processor power to handle things that can be done on the server side. Letting the device to this will take a longer time to load the data i guess. But what approach did you have in mind for the client side?

Comment: If you're sending JSON to the client, the client should be able to parse JSON. If it isn't, a simpler data format that doesn't need complex parsing would be more appropriate. Perhaps CSV or a custom form of it. Depends on what kind of data structures you want to send.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `str_replace`, like this:

```
<?php
echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($images));
?>
```

You can also try `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, like this:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($images,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have no idea how long ive been trying to solve this. The 1st code works. But the second code gives an error i don't know what it is:                            Notice (8): Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES' [APP/views/images/json/index.ctp, line 3]
Warning (2): json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given [APP/views/images/json/index.ctp, line 3]

Comment: Maybe your version of PHP isn't new enough for the second method (you need 5.4.0 or greater, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) - but at least the first method worked!